# jQuery element not displaying

Tags: jquery

The function below display two box elements, each with it's own message, one below the other. I cannot get the #managerbtns element to appear at all. I have it initially hidden along with the #managermsg element, but it never appears anywhere on the page. Only the #managermsg box fades in. I've tried to alter the properties for the #managerbtns element, but nothing works.

```
function DeleteUser(id, deleting){

var message = "<h1>Are you sure? All records associated with this user will be deleted also.</h1>";
var btns = "<a href=# class=delete id="+id+">Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=# class=cancel id="+id+">Cancel</a>";

$('#managermsg').html(message);
$('#managerbtns').html(btns);
$('#managermsg').fadeIn(500);
$('#managerbtns').fadeIn(500);
};
```

Comment: Without seeing your HTML no one can help you.

Comment: look at the rendered html in the browser... are you sure it is adding the message and btn html in

Comment: What does the error console says? Check your quotes, on the 'btns' variable.

Answer (score 2):

The html in that element is broken

```
var btns = "<a href=# class=delete id="+id+">Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=# class=cancel id="+id+">Cancel</a>";
```

You need to quote those attributes:

```
var btns = "<a href='#' class='delete' id='"+id+"'>Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#' class='cancel' id='"+id+"'>Cancel</a>";
```

Also, you're creating two anchor elements with the **same id**.  That's absolutely bad.  Either change one of the ids, or just get rid of one.

Comment: The #managermsg element has no display property either, but it works fine.

Comment: Let me clarify more, the #managerbtns element is a copy of the #managermsg element. The only difference is the top property is higher to allow it to appear below #managermsg. But for some reason, it never appears.

Comment: @stevenpepe - that doesn't change what I said.  You need to quote the attributes, and not have duplicate ids.

Comment: @stevenpepe - and you're not setting visibility:hidden anywhere, are you?

Comment: @stevenpepe what wont work ? what error ? can you include your HTML or create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @stevenpepe - just try setting the html of this element to XXXXXX and see if that displays.

Answer (score 0):

None of the attribute value in `<a href=# class=delete id="+id+">Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=# class=cancel id="+id+">Cancel</a>` is in quotes.
 try changing it like below

```
var btns = "<a href='#' class='delete' id='"+id+"'>Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
                               <a href='#' class='cancel' id='"+id+"'>Cancel</a>";
```